# Security - Remote file injection -- help needed

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, spam

I have a webshop (magento platform) but the site was **has been disabled by the hosting**.

The problem is **remote file injection** to upload scripts and spam through the website.

**How can I prevent the webshop from this injection?** Do I also need to remove the current script? if so what script?

----This is the spam email:

```
MESSAGE NUMBER 23839496:

Received: (qmail 332236 invoked by uid 783); 16 Feb 2012 18:49:03 +0100
Date: 16 Feb 2012 18:49:03 +0100

Message-ID: 
To: fpwstockn@aol.com
Subject: Give your woman night full of live
From: 

The only technique to unleash your love life http://dilahdilot.com/floor.html
```

Comment: Upload a backup from a point in time where you know that the website was not yet injected. Then update the shop software to the newest version.

Comment: I would suggest you speak to the guys from Magento. They should provide support for their products.

Comment: It might also be useful to ask this question at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your PHP scripts have been replaced with trojans, then you'll need to wipe and restore.  If your scripts are intact, and are being used to invoke qmail based on bad query parameters, then follow these steps:

Step 1: Look through your logs for "Give your woman night full of live" to figure out which script was used to inject code, or look for a single script that invokes `qmail`.

Step 2: Ask another question on SO or https://security.stackexchange.com/ , showing the code of the problematic script, and we can point you at the problem.